# Wait until all dependencies are loaded in controller - resolve without $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS provides with the RouteProvider https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider the resolve property. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them until all to them are resolved.

But how can I solve this issue when the controller is not mentioned in the route because I'm using something like ng-include or

```
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl"></div>
```

Any hints are welcome.